# Lots and lots of files on content.mso folder

Tags: microsoft-infopath

Something came up on one of our servers, the content.mso folder of the default user profile is getting filled up with thousands of temporary files. The folder size ends up in the gigabytes, son when a user without a profile logs in, it gets a copy of the default user profile. So the server quickly grows out of disk space.

A little context:

In this server we have a PDF printer (AmyUni) and a Asp.Net application running on IIS6 with a dedicated user, on the application we do Infopath Automation and send a document to the printer.

Is there any way, that either the the pdf printer or infopath (uses IE internally) are sending so many files to the default user profile?

Thanks in advance!!

PS: I found out that the bulk of the temporary files are embedded images that may come with the infopath forms, but i'm still at a loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after tearing my eyes out with this i found out a way to solve it and a probable cause for it.

This only happens when infopath is called from an iis worker process, and while the COM server ends up running with the application pool user, the process owner is at the time the LocalSystem Account, so thats why temp files are written to the default user profile.

The only way to solve it i found was to specify in de DCOM configuration screen, that the launching user should always be the application pool user for automation scenarios.

That solved it, no more hundreds of file each time we use the application.

Hope this helps someone out there.